# Static Reference to C# Web Services

Tags: c#, web-services

In the below code, I have statically created reference to my Web Service and using the same reference across many Web Service calls.

Do you guys see any issue in this pattern of reusing Web Service reference?

```
namespace Delegate
{
    public sealed class SingletonDocDelegate
    {
       private SingletonDocDelegate() {}
       public static readonly var Instance = new SingletonDocDelegate();        
       //Web Service Reference
       private readonly var _globalDocWS   = new Document.GlobalDocWS();
       public string GetTransactionalDocuments(string request)
       {
           return _globalDocWS.GetTransDocuments(request);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad. By doing that you are calling everything on the same thread, wich can cause slowdown problems. Basically you're using the same client over and over again for everything, if you make a request every 60secs it is ok, but for something more intensive you will have a bottleneck.

Idealy if you want it isolated and accessed by several projects, like for example a reference to an OData Service, you add it to a new Class Library project and leave it there alone. Since it doesn't reference anything on it's own, you can easly use it anywhere in your project.

Comment: David, I disagree on your point that it would execute on the same thread. Having a single object does not mean that all requests will be executed on the same thread. If you underlying service is stateless, I dont see any performance issues with this code - K